# USB Power Draw Plug In Order

Tags: usb, power, usb-power, power-management

I'm having some issues running a USB webcam and a USB speaker at the same time. If I plug in my webcam second, both devices work perfectly fine. If I simply boot with both plugged in, the speaker doesn't seem to get enough power and stops responding. Wondering what my options are, aside from a powered USB hub and simply plugging in the webcam second every time I fire up the Raspi.

Some things I've tried:

usbreset on the specific devices, to try to get the power draw issue fixed without unplugging/replugging

killing the USB power completely (on Raspi 3B port 2 has power control ability and kills all ports) using uhubctl, and re-enabling the power after some time

My power supply is 2.5A on Raspi 3B, MaxPower on the USB Camera is 500mA and MaxPower on the speaker is 400mA

Comment: Are you using the official power supply?

Comment: You probably need the powered USB hub. Why did you write that out as an option?

Comment: I'm not 100% against it, but I'd rather not spend more money when the setup has proven to work reliably if you plug the devices in in the correct order. Seems like if that is possible, there may potentially be a software solution.